# How to calculate Rolling Correlation with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I understand how to calculate a rolling sum, std or average. Example:

```
df['MA10'] = df['Asset1'].rolling(10).mean()
```

But I don't understand the syntax to calculate the rolling correlation between two dataframes columns: `df['Asset1']` and `df['Asset2']`

The documentation doesn't provide any example regarding the correlation.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Any insights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's in there, even if hidden a bit:

```
df['Asset1'].rolling(10).corr(df['Asset2'])
```

Comment: What's best way to visualize this kind of output?

Answer (score 1):

It's a way slower (~3x) and a bit longer, but in some cases more illustrative:

```
df[['Asset1','Asset2']].rolling(10).corr().unstack().iloc[:,0]
```

Multiple assets:

```
df[['Asset1','Asset2','Asset3']].rolling(100).corr().unstack().iloc[:,[0,1]]
```