# Calculating rolling correlation gives values much bigger than 1

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to calculate rolling window correlation following [How to calculate Rolling Correlation with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957186/how-to-calculate-rolling-correlation-with-pandas). I have a [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMYGc.png) with two columns and a datetime index.

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |   temperature_pair1 |   temperature_pair2 |
|---------------------+---------------------+---------------------|
| 2019-04-16 09:06:00 |               22.69 |               22.69 |
| 2019-04-16 09:07:00 |               22.69 |               22.69 |
| 2019-04-16 09:08:00 |               22.69 |               22.69 |
| 2019-04-16 09:09:00 |               22.75 |               22.69 |
| 2019-04-16 09:10:00 |               22.69 |               22.69 |
| 2019-04-16 09:11:00 |               22.69 |               22.75 |
| 2019-04-16 09:12:00 |               22.75 |               22.75 |
| 2019-04-16 09:13:00 |               22.75 |               22.75 |
| 2019-04-16 09:14:00 |               22.75 |               22.75 |
| 2019-04-16 09:15:00 |               22.75 |               22.75 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I'm applying the same methods shown in the question, `foi.temperature_pair1.rolling(window_size).corr(foi.temperature_pair2)`, but the resulting dataframe has values [outside of the range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt0vw.png) `[-1,  1]`. What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Can you copy your actual data in the post and not as an image?

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard)

Comment: That can't be copied easily back into a dataframe.  However, the link I gave, also shows how to get a reproducible dataset from colab.

Comment: Do the following: **1:** `foi_corr = pd.DataFrame(foi.temperature_pair1.rolling(10).corr(foi.temperature_pair2)).rename(columns={0: 'corr'})` **2:** `print(foi_corr.min())` **3:** `print(foi_corr.max())` **4:** `foi_corr.plot()` **5:** Edit the question  and add the information from these instructions. You can change `10` to your preferred window size, but include that information back in the question.

Comment: Also, can you share a link to this dataset?