# How to get correlation for a rolling pandas series and a fixed series?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I want to calculate corr between two series. I defined them as:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
s2 = pd.Series([2,3,4])
```

what i want is a correlation series, that the values is the corr between s.rolling(3) with s2

For example: the first element of result should be [1,2,3].corr(s2), the second should be [2,3,4].corr(s2), .....

I read the usage example of rolling, but i think it inner method rolling(3).corr cant solve this,
is there any good methods to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate Rolling Correlation with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957186/how-to-calculate-rolling-correlation-with-pandas)

Comment: no, but still thanks for noticing this @WBM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do a rolling apply:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
s.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: pearsonr(x,s2)[0])
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a for loop?

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
s2 = pd.Series([2,3,4])
window_size = len(s2)

output = []
for i in range(len(s)-window_size):
    output.append(s[i:window_size+i].corr(s2))
```