# How to get correlation from fixed series and rolling dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-rolling

Can someone help me? I want to run correlation with fixed Series in `df` and rolling DataFrame in `df1`. Desired result should be all 1 from index 1 to 6 but I got NaN.

```
df = pd.Series([2,3,4])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'B':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70],
                   'C':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700]})

def x(y):
    return y.corr(df)

df2 = df1.rolling(window=len(df),min_periods=1).apply(x)

[out] =

    A   B   C
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   1.0 1.0 1.0
2   1.0 1.0 1.0
3   1.0 1.0 1.0
4   NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN
6   NaN NaN NaN

Desired result:

    A   B   C
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   1.0 1.0 1.0
2   1.0 1.0 1.0
3   1.0 1.0 1.0
4   1.0 1.0 1.0
5   1.0 1.0 1.0
6   1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: I think you might want [expanding.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html) `df2 = df1.expanding().apply(x)` (or `df2 = df1.expanding(min_periods=2).apply(x)` to avoid a RuntimeWarning) but it's a bit hard to tell with such generic expected output.

Comment: Thanks Henry for the feedback, it is helpful, but i found that the NaN values in index 4,5,6 is a copy from previous row.

Comment: for instance, I need the operation in:
index 4, column A = correlation between df[2,3,4] and df1['A'][3,4,5] 
index 5,col A = correlation between df[2,3,4] and df1['A'][4,5,6]. 
index 6,col A =correlation between df[2,3,4] and df1['A'][5,6,7]
and do the same operation with other columns

Comment: i found some reference here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913597/how-to-get-correlation-for-a-rolling-pandas-series-and-a-fixed-series but it use pearsonr which does not deal with min_periods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create same index in `y` and `df`, here is default index in `df`, so is necessary [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
def x(y):
    return y.reset_index(drop=True).corr(df)

df2 = df1.rolling(window=len(df),min_periods=1).apply(x)
print (df2)
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
5  1.0  1.0  1.0
6  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: It works jezrael! many,many,many Thanks to you..